# I dont get any output or reponse from my GET method in my php code

Tags: php, html, get

So im trying to make a search bar that will fill my table but my code seems to be not working

```
<?php $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","e-learning") or 
die ("Error");
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_info"; 
$queryResult = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);

if(isset($_GET ['submit'])&& !empty($_GET['submit'])){
$safe_value = $GET['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_info 
WHERE`first_name`like'"."%".$safe_value."%"."'";
$queryResult = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);
}
?>
```

this is my html code:

```
<form method="GET">
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>          
  </form>
```

this is my table

```
      <?php

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) {?>
               <tr>

               <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
               <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['middle_name']." ".$row['last_name']  ?></td>

                <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['user_level'];?></td>
                 <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>



               </tr>
          <?php     }
             ?>
```

ps: i get the output from the first query but whenever i click the go search button i cannot get the second one

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Use mysqli_error to check for errors after executing sql Statements

Comment: Does the query even get performed?  It seems to me your `form` should have an `action` attribute.

Comment: im really new in web developing im sorry for that, can you show me the part where i make mistake ? thank you in advance

Comment: Is it typo `if(isset($_GET ['submit'])` of spacing

Comment: do an echo 'test'; after your if statement to see if your statement is working correctly. I think as mentioned the space could be causing issues.

Comment: @user2486 thank you bro its working now!!! to be honest i skipped the fundamental of web programming thats why im in this position im so doomed =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things off...

1. Your button has two types`<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>` so get rid off the type="button".
2. Your missing the action attribute in your form tags so turn `<form method="GET">` into `<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">` considering the PHP script is on the same page as the html code.
3. Delete the name/id attributes of your buttons because you don't need them ( unless you need the ID attribute for CSS ).
4. In your php script, you are looking if the button is set and has some value which is wrong... in GET request you should be checking your data, nothing to do with the button so replace `if(isset($_GET ['submit'])&& !empty($_GET['submit'])){` with `if(isset($_GET ['search'])&& !empty($_GET['search'])){`
5. You misstyped `$safe_value = $GET['search'];` because you should have `$_GET['search']`

However, all of these could've been discovered by you if you looked more carefully at your code.

Here is the full functional code:

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","e-learning") or 
die ("Error");
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_info"; 
$queryResult = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);


if(isset($_GET ['search'])&& !empty($_GET['search'])){
$safe_value = $_GET['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_info 
WHERE`first_name`like'"."%".$safe_value."%"."'";
$queryResult = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-secondary">Go!</button>
  </span>          
  </form><br/><br/>
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) { ?>
        <tr>
               <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
               <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['middle_name']." ".$row['last_name']  ?></td>

                <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['user_level'];?></td>
                 <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
        </tr><br/>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the tips... now i understand better how to construct php code ty